# How much overhead space do rows in SE tables consume?

Tags: informix

I have a row length of 499 bytes. How many bytes per row does SE use to store the row in the datafile?

How many rows will fit in a 2K page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one byte of overhead.  Each row is terminated by either a newline (not deleted) or a null byte (deleted).

However, SE uses C-ISAM and C-ISAM does not use pages for the data.  Consecutive rows are simply stored consecutively.  The index file uses pages, but not the data file.

Comment: Do columns with NULL values still consume  the column fixed length? How much overhead is there on each index node in 2K pagesize?

Comment: In SE, all rows are always fixed length and all fields in the row, whether null or not, are fixed length.  For the index page structure and hence overhead, I would have to go read the relevant appendix in the C-ISAM manual.  It's a long time (a decade or more) since I needed to know that.

Comment: If there's only 1 byte overhead per row, why does the data appear garbled, with unprintable characters, when viewing SE datafiles?

Comment: Because INT values are stored as binary with unprintable characters; so are SMALLINT, FLOAT, SMALLFLOAT, DECIMAL values.  Only CHAR values are stored readably (and even then, that assumes you stored readable data).  C-ISAM data is a binary format, not a text format.

Comment: You can find the C-ISAM manual in the [IBM Publications Center](https://www-05.ibm.com/e-business/linkweb/publications/servlet/pbi.wss?CTY=US&FNC=SRX&PBL=G251-0448-00).  Appendix D File Formats describes the structure of the index file.  Note that SE does not support variable-length fields so the C-ISAM files created by SE never have 'remainder storage nodes'.  The information is sufficiently long that I'm not ready to transcribe it into the main answer.  If the question were about "What is the structure of a C-ISAM index file?" then maybe, but it would be simply regurgitating the manual.

Comment: Also note that the index nodes (pages) are either 512 or 1024 bytes, not 2048.  The 'length - 1' value is stored in 2 bytes at offset 6 (bytes) in the zeroth block of the index file.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read the C-ISAM documentation. Did RDS create C-ISAM? IIRC, C-ISAM was also used in other products such as Btrieve?

Comment: Yes.  RDS (Relational Database Systems Inc, which became Informix when it went public) did invent C-ISAM.  It was incorporated into (at least) one version of the XPG (X/Open Portability Guide) as a standard — if you're careful, you can dig up that specification.  And as a result, there are a number of very similar products still available.  (X/Open Developers’ Specification:
Indexed Sequential Access Method (ISAM) ISBN: 1 872630 03 0.  Published 1990.)

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if IDS' RSAM was derived from C-ISAM?.. There's virtually no RSAM info available when googling it.

Comment: Yes, RSAM was based on ISAM but is vastly different. It was never made available separately from Turbo, OnLine, ODS, IDS, XPS, IUS, … the non-SE SQL-based Informix servers.

Comment: Is the C-ISAM Datablade that bridges with IDS still available or supported?

Comment: .. many would be surprised that there's still a lot of legacy SE applications still running, especially embedded one's.